# Split string into array by letters

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to split a string into an array such that if the string is
`z10k4m42` it would become

```
array('z' => 10, 'k' => 4, 'm' => 42)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: harsh and uninviting comments. even worse, snarky and counterproductive.

Answer (score 6):

Try the below:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z]+)(\d+)/', 'z10k4m42', $matches);
$ret = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Comment: This only makes an array with the numbers. The solution would be a mix with my (deleted) answer and yours :-)

Comment: This at least works for me. I got an array with chars as key and the following numbers as value. Isn't that what he wanted?

Comment: @TheDisintegrator Have you run the code and see the result? It should be what the op wants.